# Optimality of the uniform distribution for a load balancing problem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, balls-in-bins

For some $n ∈ ℕ$, you have $n$ buckets with given *capacities* $c_1,…,c_n ∈ ℕ$ and given *average loads* $λ_1,…,λ_n ∈ ℝ_{≥ 0}$. You may choose probabilities $p_1,…,p_n ∈ [0,1]$.

Now, for $i ∈ [n]$ independently, we put a Poisson distributed number $X_i \sim \mathrm{Po}(λ_i)$ of balls into bucket $i$, with each ball independently coloured **red** with probability $p_i$ and **blue** otherwise.

We say a bucket $i ∈ [n]$ is *overflowing* if $X_i > c_i$. The *total overflow* is $T = \sum_{i ∈ [n]} \max\{0,X_i-c_i\}$.

You *lose* if

1. the total overflow is $T = 2$ **and**
2. all balls in overflowing buckets have the same colour.

**Question: Is the probability to lose minimised by $p_1 = p_2 = … = p_n = \frac{1}{2}$, regardless of $(λ_i)_{i ∈ [n]}$ and $(c_i)_{i ∈ [n]}$?**

Note: If 1. holds, then either one bucket overflows by two balls or two buckets overflow by one ball. We may zoom in on these cases since the colours of the balls (and thus $(p_i)_{i ∈ [n]}$) are irrelevant if 1. does not hold.

PS: We suspect that a positive answer could imply a more difficult (but also more natural) claim: Namely, that the probability of a $k$-uniform hypergraph with $n$ vertices and $m$ hyperedges to be *orientable* is maximised if the $m$ edges of the hypergraph are generated according to the uniform distribution on $\binom{[n]}{k}$ (as opposed to being generated by any other distribution).

Comment: To be clear: if $T = 2$ and it happens that two distinct buckets $i$ and $j$ overflow by one ball each, you require the color of balls in bin $i$ to be the same as the color of balls in bin $j$. Is that correct?

Comment: It seems to me that if $p_i$ are the only parameter we can vary, then yes, $p_i=\frac12$ would be the optimal strategy regardless of the $\lambda_i$ and $c_i$. Since it's not like we can do anything about the overflow.

Comment: @snar: correct.
To clarify further: There is two types of bad events:
**(i)** For each $i ∈ [n]$, bucket $i$ overflows by $2$, no other bucket overflows, and all balls in bucket $i$ have the same colour. The probability for this event is minimised by choosing $p_i = 1/2$.
**(ii)** For each $i,j ∈ [n]$, $i ≠ j$, the event that both buckets $i$ and $j$ overflow by $1$, no other bucket overflows and all balls in buckets $i$ and $j$ have the same colour. The probability for this event vanishes if $p_i = 1$ and $p_j = 0$ (or vice versa).

Thus the events somehow pull in different directions.

Answer (score 1):

This may be true, and comes down to doing some algebra. I haven't had time to finish up this answer in a clean way, but it is too long for a comment, so I post it here in case it may be useful. I only treat the case $n = 2$, and have only checked some cases numerically.

Let $B_i$ be the event that all the balls in bucket $i$ are the same color, and $B_{12}$ the event that the balls in both buckets are the same color. The event of interest is the union of three disjoint events, $E = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3.$
\begin{align*}
E_1 &= \{ X_1 = c_1+2, X_2 \leq c_2, B_1\} \\
E_2 &= \{X_2 = c_2+2, X_1 \leq c_1, B_2\}\\
E_3 &= \{X_1 = c_1+1, X_2=c_2+1, B_{12}\}.
\end{align*}
The probabilities for these events are easy to write down. For instance,
\begin{align*}
P(E_1) &= P(X_1 = c_1+2, B_1) P(X_2 \leq c_2) \\
&=(p_1^{c_1+2}+(1-p_1)^{c_1+2}) \frac{e^{-\lambda_1} \lambda_1^{c_1+2}}{(c_1+2)!}\sum_{k \leq c_2} \frac{e^{-\lambda_2}\lambda_2^k}{k!},
\end{align*}
and similarly
$$P(E_2) = (p_2^{c_2+2}+(1-p_2)^{c_2+2}) \frac{e^{-\lambda_2} \lambda_2^{c_2+2}}{(c_2+2)!}\sum_{k \leq c_1} \frac{e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^k}{k!}.$$
For $E_3$,
\begin{align*}
P(E_3) &= P(B_{12}|X_1,X_2)P(X_1=c_1+1,X_2=c_2+1)\\
&= (p_1^{c_1+1}p_2^{c_2+1}+(1-p_1)^{c_1+1}(1-p_2)^{c_2+1}) \frac{e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^{c_1+1}}{(c_1+1)!} \frac{e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^{c_2+1}}{(c_2+1)!}.
\end{align*}
Thus we can write
$$P(E) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+P(E_3) = a_1 f_1(p_1) + a_2 f_2(p_2) + a_3 f_3(p_1,p_2).$$
From here it comes down to taking derivatives w.r.t. $p_1, p_2$ and solving the system of equations. Alternatively, one should be able to reduce it to whether
$$ a_1 f_1(0.5) + a_2 f_2(0.5)  + a_3 f_3(0.5, 0.5) \leq a_1 f(0) + a_2 f(1) + a_3 f_3 (0, 1),$$
where the $a_j$ depend on $c_i, \lambda_i$,
and whether the same inequality holds true for $(p_1,p_2) = (1, 0)$. If it does, then $(1/2, 1/2)$ is the optimal selection of $p_i$'s in this case.

Comment: It is plausible that calculations like this can handle the case of $n = 2$. However, I don't feel like I can box this through for general $n ∈ ℕ$. I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: Well, just do $n=3$ and $n=4$ and see if you can spot a pattern. You have all the independence you need to write down the likelihoods of the various events. For instance, given that two buckets overflowed by 1 each, the probability that buckets $i$ and $j$ overflowed by $1$ (as opposed to any other pair of buckets) is proportional to $P(X_i = c_i+1, X_j = c_j+1,\cap_{k\neq i,j} X_k \leq c_k)$. It shouldn't be intractable, it just requires work.